# Academic Gurobi for free on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, gurobi

[Gurobi gives free license for academic use](http://www.gurobi.com/academia/academia-center). I want to use Gurobi on Amazon EC2 while doing MapReduce processes. [There is a Gurobi service being provided by Amazon EWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00M3A695U), but it is too expensive. This is gonna be much more for MapReduce which needs lots of machines, each using Gurobi simultaneously. I wonder if anyone has tried to deploy the academic license for using Gurobi on EC2.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on this for later in 2015.  You should contact us directly at Gurobi.